# Getting code hints to work for external JavaScript file (.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

I am wondering how I can import jquery into a .js file. I want to be able to use codehints (intellinse) but given this is a separate file, I cannot do that. Maybe I don't have to import, but is there any way to get

```
$().[hint]
```

to show up inside a standalone .js file?

Comment: in my IDE (netbeans), this works out-of-the-box

Comment: I am using Visual Studio unfortunately (though I have to say that I would much rather use netbeans, however I cannot :()

Comment: I work with DW CS6 and it has native jQuery auto-complete. Most of the time I prefer to write the code without any codehinting though, my creativity works best this way IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this at the beginning of your js file

```
/// <reference path="/js/jquery.js" />
```

Comment: You can add it by dragging it from "Solution Explorer" to your js file.

Comment: I grab jQuery off the google resource, but it works wonderfully if I add /// <reference path="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js" />

Answer (score 0):

Here's microsoft's page on intellisense for javascript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx

I've used their format and it works generally well.  jQuery has an exports (jquery-[version]-vsdoc.js or something similar) that you place in your Scripts directory.

Then you add `///<reference path="path/to/jquery-[version].js" />` at the top of your script and everything just seems to work (for most things).

There's very limited documentation on the schema but I have created a rough XSD of what the schema looks like (VS doesn't pick up all the things they claim to support though)

EDIT: if you install SP1 for VS2010 you should get the latest support for JS intellisense.  If not, microsoft has an extension for supporting it.  To get the -vsdoc.js file mentioned above, the easiest way is to get it through nuget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <!-- Schema is based on http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx -->
  <!-- para tags are not specced on that page but are included as part of the VS JScript Editor Extensions -->
  <!-- The "End" tag is a wrapper tag so I can make a valid document -->
  <xs:element name="End">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="reference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="referenceType"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="summary" type="TextContent"/>
          <xs:element name="param" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ParamNamedTypedTextContent" />
          <xs:element name="field" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="NamedTypedTextContent" />
          <xs:element name="returns" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="TypedTextContent" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="referenceType">
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="assembly" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="TextContent" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="para" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="locid" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="TypedTextContent">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TextContent">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="elementType" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="integer" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="mayBeNull" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="domElement" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="elementInteger" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="elementDomElement" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="elementMayBeNull" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="NamedTypedTextContent">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TypedTextContent">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ParamNamedTypedTextContent">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="NamedTypedTextContent">
        <xs:attribute name="optional" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

EDIT2:
Here's an example of some of my code written using VS intellisense supported tags:

```
function getDottedProperty(obj, dottedPropertyChain) {
    ///<summary>
    ///  <para>
    ///    Returns the property of the object given by the dotted property
    ///     chain.
    ///  </para>
    ///  <para>
    ///    Example:
    ///      GetDottedProperty(
    ///          { a: { b: { c: { d: 'hello' } } } },
    ///          'a.b.c.d'
    ///      )
    ///  </para>
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="obj" type="Object">Object</param>
    ///<param name="dottedPropertyChain" type="String">
    ///  The string of properties to access.
    ///</param>

    var propertySplits = dottedPropertyChain.split('.');
    while (propertySplits.length) {
        obj = obj[propertySplits.shift()];
    }

    return obj;
}
```